# Resize image keeping aspect ratio

Tags: c#, image, resize

After combing through all the solutions here, when applying them in my code, Visual Studio alerts to the fact that the code will only run on windows. Are there any resizing algorithms that will work on ALL OS? MAC and Windows ?

I am running a Blazor server application so the code will be running on .Net core.
Thanks.

Update :
[image]

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: @gunr2171  Thanks for your efforts. I did solve this eventually by just adding a "Width" property to my image, Bootstrap "fluid" property then resized for me. I followed the "Keep it simple stupid rule" !  I guess I did post an image so that I could highlight the lines needed to be attended to .  Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solve this eventually by just adding a "Width" property to my image, Bootstrap "fluid" class property then resized for me. Note, for responsive to work, no height property was added, only the width.